# question related to the convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, gamma-function

Can anyone tell to which the following series converges?
$\frac{\sqrt{2-s}}{\Gamma(1.5)}-\frac{(\sqrt{2-s})^3}{\Gamma(2.5)}+\frac{(\sqrt{2-s})^5}{\Gamma(3.5)}-\frac{(\sqrt{2-s})^7}{\Gamma(4.5)}+\frac{(\sqrt{2-s})^9}{\Gamma(5.5)}-....$ where $s\in [0, 2]$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n }{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}x^{2 n+1}=e^{-x^2}\, \text{erfi}(x)$$ where appears the imaginary error function